# nginx proxy to tomcat hiding address

Tags: tomcat, nginx, proxy

I am trying to set nginx as a reverse proxy to a Tomcat (which runs on the same box).

The nginx server runs on port 9001 and i would like to proxy any requests to tomcat (which runs on port 8080), but i would like to prevent the user seeing tomcat's actual address in his/her browser bar.

I have the below nginx server configuration:

```
server {
    listen       9001;
    server_name  myHostname.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myHostname.com:8080;

         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

When i try to access http://myHostname:9001 from my browser it redirects me to http://myHostname:8080. I would like to be able to access http://myHostname:9001 and view the web app that is deployed in Tomcat but without my browser's bar to reveal Tomcat's port.

Is that possible using nginx ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First remove `proxy_redirect off`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I have removed that line, but the behaviour remains the same

Comment: Well, then check which server sends redirect and what is exactly in that redirect.